# Mockito Error "Value must not be null" on when thenReturn with any()

Tags: java, spring, unit-testing, junit, mockito

I have the following code in my unit tests to simulate database calls:

```
Mockito.when(valueRepository.findAllByDateBetweenAndValueContent_BoolVal(
        any(LocalDate.class),
        any(LocalDate.class),
        anyBoolean()
)).thenReturn(new ArrayList<>());
```

Whenever I try to run my code I get the following error:

```
org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: Value must not be null!; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Value must not be null!
```

I tried messing around with the Return value and with the Inputs (any...) but I couldn't find a solution and I don't really understand what value is null / what spring is complaining about.

The valueRepository - variable was initialized correctly, I checked with debug that it is not null.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found my error: I inserted the valueRepository variable with Autowired instead of MockBean:

wrong / before:

```
@Autowired
ValueRepository valueRepository;
```

correct / after:

```
@MockBean
ValueRepository valueRepository;
```

With this change it works now.
The error message wasn't very helpful unfortunately

Comment: There is an `InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException` in the error message. It means the real method is called ==> valueRepository is not a Mock.